# FIFO /Named Pipes in D?

Tags: c++, d

I am trying to do the following :

A central application, let us call it alpha, accepts user inputs in command lines, and based on those inputs, spawns other processes, call them bravo, charlie, etc. I want the parent and child to communicate both way. That is, alpha can read from and write to bravo (resp. charlie) and vice-versa

In C++, i can use fork() then exec(), and use FIFO-s - some excellent tutorials, are here :
[Pipe, Fork, and Exec - Two Way Communication Between Parent and Child Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191030/pipe-fork-and-exec-two-way-communication-between-parent-and-child-process?rq=1)
and
http://pronix.linuxdelta.de/C/Linuxprogrammierung/Linuxsystemprogrammieren_C_Kurs_Kapitel5b.shtml

But, I am wondering if the same, is also possible in D? I dont find much from web searching.

Comment: You can do the same things in D as you can in C and C++. import core.sys.posix.unistd; will get you fork, and I think exec and pipe too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens, I remember your previous post here and drew a conclusion two questions are related. For what you asked in the previous question ([Switch cas Alternative in D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745517/switch-cas-alternative-in-d)) you really do not need some complex interprocess communication - you basically need to call `std.process.execute()` and get the output. Think of it as a function similar to [popen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen).

Check that thread, and see how I implemented a very basic "fact" command using execute()... You should be able to build a much more robust solution on top of that code if you implement all necessary checks.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like D's standard library supports creating pipes and child processes.

http://dlang.org/phobos/std_process.html

Comment: My bad, I should have mentioned i am in D-2. I dont think phobos works with D-2 - could you also tell me about Tango support on this issue?

Comment: Tango and Phobos can work together on D2. It uses phobos by default, the dlang.org documentation is about phobos for d2.

Comment: @Sean: You are wrong. Phobos is and was the main D runtime. Tango has many nice options, indeed, but it was never the default runtime. There is the TangoD2 project which works on top of Phobos as an extra library - https://github.com/SiegeLord/Tango-D2 .